# Unix Commands interpretation

Tags: unix

what's the meaning of the following notation in Unix ?

```
:- or :=
```

what does the following means

```
if [ ${path:=0} -eq 1 ]
if [ ${path:-0} -eq 1 ]
```

Comment: Provides defaults for variables. Take a look ath http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` is a parameter expansion, so if for instance `$path` is not set, it will fall back to 0 in your example code.

Using a hyphen `:-` will use the value, and using `:=` will assign the value.

Additional info prompted by comment:

In your example, you are using a variable called `$path`, so using the `:=` will go like this: if $path is not set, set $path to the value (0 in your case). Any time you use $path afterwards it would be set to your value, 0.

Using `:-` will simply just use the default value given (again, 0 in your case) and NOT assign it to $path. Any uses of $path afterwards still be not set.

Comment: Using a hyphen :- will use the value, and using := will assign the value.
I am not sure if I get that,  "use the value " and assign the value?

Comment: I'll add extra info to the answer for you.